# Mysql Query to get latest record while using multiple joins, group by and sum()

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT Task_Entry_Icode, Task_Master_Icode, Work_Progress,SUM(A.Logged_Hours) as logged,B.*
```

FROM task_entry A INNER JOIN task_master B on A.Task_Master_Icode=B.Task_Icode

WHERE Task_Entry_Icode IN (

```
SELECT MAX(Task_Entry_Icode)

FROM task_entry

GROUP BY Task_Master_Icode
```

);

Comment: There is nothing we can work on here...

Comment: how to get sum of particular columns while using group by. before i use sum() it works correctly.

Comment: Please provide a sample data and expected result(or explain what you want to achieve) and this query that you have tried in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  B.Task_Entry_Icode, 
  B.Task_Master_Icode, 
  (SELECT Work_Progress FROM task_entry WHERE Task_Master_Icode=B.Task_Master_Icode ORDER BY B.Created_On DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0),
  SUM(B.Logged_Hours)
FROM 
  task_master A INNER JOIN task_entry B ON A.Task_Icode=B.Task_Master_Icode
GROUP BY 
  B.task_master_icode;
```

Comment: it returns no records

Comment: Could you share with us your schema and some of your data ? You can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ for this.

Comment: Dont understand what you want as result ? i updated the query but i think you want something else could you put your expectation result ?

Comment: Check this if this what you want ?

Comment: I want sum(logged_hours) in the group by

Comment: Could you put the result excepted in the question because i think i have some miss understanding thanks.

Comment: i need to sum all the values of logged hours in each group using task_master_icode. For task master icode 1 logged sum is 8. for 2 its 4 and for 3 it should be 21

Comment: SELECT 
  B.Task_Entry_Icode, B.Task_Master_Icode, B.Work_Progress, SUM(B.Logged_Hours)
FROM 
  task_master A INNER JOIN task_entry B ON A.Task_Icode=B.Task_Master_Icode
GROUP BY 
  B.task_master_icode;

Comment: this works but the work progress is not last inserted record. For the task_entry 3 it should come as Going in work progress.

Comment: Check now the new query in the answer if its fine ?

Comment: nope i need all three records.  For the task_entry 3 it should come as Going in work progress.

Comment: Check now hope its fine :)

Comment: Oh soooo happy just mark it like solution thank you ;)

Answer (score 1):

SELECT *
FROM task_master A INNER JOIN task_entry B ON A.Task_Icode=B.Task_Master_Icode
WHERE Created_On IN (
    SELECT MAX(Created_On)
    FROM task_entry 
    GROUP BY Task_Master_Icode
) AND A.Task_Created_By='7';

> this works for me but if i use sum() it returns only one record